# Is it normal for a 3-year-old to always lay down when playing?

Tags: behavior, pre-schooler, development, grandparents

I have a 3-year-old grandson. It doesn't matter where he is, ice cold tile floor or on his bed, he lays down to play.

I've read that in some children this can be a sign of a learning/sensory disability but he is a very precocious boy. One item I did read about that related to him is he doesn't like to be held upside down.  He does seem to have a type A personality where everything must be perfect or he has a serious fit.

Should I be concerned?  If so, what should I do?

Comment: Note that being precocious doesn't preclude a learning disability.  This situation is common enough to have its own name: [twice exceptional](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twice_exceptional).

Answer (score 9):

I don't like to be held upside down either. I wouldn't read anything into that. As to playing on the floor, I teach eighth grade, and when I let my 14 year olf students move around the classroom to work with friends, a third will end up laying on the floor, working on their math.

As for the fits, he may be frustrated with his wants outpacing his abilities. If he talks, walks, eats, and is generally age appropriate, I wouldn't worrying too much about frustration just yet.

Answer (score 2):

My son still does this occasionally (he's nearly 6). He is a very sensory child and we have been address this (described [here](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/11201/suggestions-for-a-5-year-old-who-cant-sit-still-in-her-chair/11206#11206)) for the past year. If your grandson is craving sensory input, they it is not a bad thing. Are there any other signs of him sensory seeking? Such as:

- chewing toys, pencils, etc...
- bumping into things and people
- rolling on the floor if stressed or overloaded

*If* he is sensory seeking, you need to work with him. He is already self-medicating, you (and the parents) need to support that process and help him get better.

Another possible cause is that the child may lack core body strength. Many children these days do not have a strong core so it is hard for them to sit straight. This can be seen, for example, in the way they write/draw. A weak child may hold their breath while drawing to help keep their body rigid.

Or it could be something else but keep in mind that children rarely do things for no reason.

Answer (score 0):

Consider issues of core strength or consider issues with motor planning. Or, maybe whatever he is playing is better suited to be played in a prone position.